# dynamic subdomain does not draw $_GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

So trough the big hassle of this finding for the right script and yadayadayada I now have a CNAME redirecting myawesomeblog.mysite.com to mysite.com/?blog=myawesomeblog and a .htaccess code like the following

```
RewriteEngine On

# Prevent people from going to to index.php directly and spoofing the
# subdomain value, since this may not be a desirable action
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\index\.php.*(\?|&)blog=
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?blog=%1
```

It all works, except that I need to get *.mysite.com/?get=something&get2=something-more working as well, I have no idea how to make it happen tho'

All help is appreciated.

Comment: For debugging add [R] to the rewrite rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need an extra flag to your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?blog=%1 [L,QSA]
```

R as in redirect. L as in last. QSA as in *query string append*.

Comment: Thanks, case closed. Worked perfectly.